# Connection error in AWS RDS SSL in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to RDS through Lambda NodeJS 12.x with SSL. However I am receiving these errors:

```
  Error: 4506652096:error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:
  library: 'SSL routines',
  function: 'ssl_choose_client_version',
  reason: 'unsupported protocol',
  code: 'HANDSHAKE_SSL_ERROR'
```

I am connecting like this:

```
const pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit     : 10,
  host                : 'db.cqgcxllqwqnk.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
  ssl                 : {
    ca                : fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/rds-ca-2019-root.pem')
  },
  user                : ‘xxxxx’,
  password            : ‘xxxxxx’,
  database            : ‘xxxxxx’,
  multipleStatements  : true
});
```

When I connect with the certificate through MySql Workbench everything works just fine.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was related to Mysql version and TLS version. This matrix shows that for MySQL 5.6 only TLS 1.0 is supported. Node.js 12 by default uses TLS 1.2.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport

Answer (score -1):

Do this before connect as this have insufficent permission over file

```
sudo chmod 755 rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
```

> Warning: keep a strong password, this password easily guessable

if you still find problem, check IAM permission to lambda or check whether both RDS and lambda in same VPC.

Comment: Then this might be vpc or iam problem